# Go to Next page when a separate button from pagination?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I go to next page when a button "Press me" is pressed?
Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.3.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="PaginationDemoCtrl">

    <pagination num-pages="noOfPages" current-page="currentPage" max-size="maxSize"></pagination>
    The selected page no: {{currentPage}}
</div>

<button>Press me</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/NVgCX8nrx0ovnCWE2eok?p=preview

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Try to be a little more specific in what you are trying to do and what you have tried already. Please read the [tips on how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it will help you get a good answer sooner. A good tip is to add some code here, so that we can see what you are trying to do and what the problems might be, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

... Your question is pretty vague, but I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
<button value='Press me' onClick='document.location="./NVgCX8nrx0ovnCWE2eok?p=preview"'>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html move your controller to the body tag and add a click event for the button

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.3.0.js"></script>
        <script src="example.js"></script>
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="PaginationDemoCtrl">
        <div>
            <pagination num-pages="noOfPages" current-page="currentPage" max-size="maxSize"></pagination>
            The selected page no: {{currentPage}}
        </div>
        <button ng-click="goToNext()">Press me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

In your script add a function to handle the click event. I simply increment the current page number.

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var PaginationDemoCtrl = function($scope) {
  $scope.noOfPages = 20;
  $scope.currentPage = 4;
  $scope.maxSize = 5;

  $scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
    $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
  };

  $scope.goToNext = function() {
    $scope.currentPage = ++$scope.currentPage;
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Link to Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/8SPBGbvkBbtMj59XXj6M?p=preview)**

1. move `ng-controller="PaginationDemoCtrl"` to body tag.
2. add directive to button `ng-click="setPage(currentPage+1)`

---

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.3.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="PaginationDemoCtrl">

    <div>
      <pagination num-pages="noOfPages" current-page="currentPage" max-size="maxSize"></pagination>
      The selected page no: {{currentPage}}
    </div>

    <button ng-click="setPage(currentPage+1)">Press me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```